Why would a clover field die off?
Back in early spring of 2022 I planted a large micro-clover field over a weed infested area by:

putting down cardboard
adding 4 to 6" of fill-soil on top of the cardboard
sowing clover and perennials

It worked really well during 2022 & 2023.  The clover would died during the height of summer but came back in spring.
But this year the clover simply did not come back, despite having lots of rain.
I always thought clover takes care of itself - how can I troubleshoot this problem?  Is the soil missing something?
I put a lot of hard work into the area 2 years ago and would really like to salvage the area :-)

Is something else growing in the clover's place, or is it barren?

Well, weeds are starting to take over, I am weeding it for now but there are a lot of barren spots as well

Are the perennials coming back, or have they died, too?

The perennials are coming back: lupins, california poppies, baby blue eyes

Depending on the kind of clover it can be the pH value of the soil. Some love chalk, others love sour soil. By getting a list of indication-plants and compare with the other plants in the place you can find out what kind of soil you have :)

Perhaps take a soil sample and sow clover again, see if it grows.

@Vorac I tried that back in April or March (can't remember now).  The baby blue eyes that were newly sown came up in patches but nothing about the clover...

Supposing the sample size was enough (say 5 pots taken from different locations) and the experiment was controlled for external factors(e.g. indoors as to isolate from weather) then now we know it's the soil(or organisms in it). In Your shoes I would ask a separate question where the cardboard and weeds would be irrelevant.
